# How can I set a form to have a transparent background

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am struggling to get my form to have a transparent background in vb.net

Currently in the form New I set

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true)
```

But still the form shows up as having the default grey background

Can anyone help??

EDIT: I need the controls on the form to be visible so I don't think setting the opacity to 0 will work

EDIT: I tried the transparency key solution  but it doesn't work. I have a circular image with a black background. OnPaint I set the transparency key to the img pixel at 0,0, this then leaves me with circular image (which I want ) It hides the black background but I am still left with the default grey rectangle of the form.

below is the code I have -

```
Public Sub New()

    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub frmWoll_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Dim img As Bitmap = CType(Me.BackgroundImage, Bitmap)

    img.MakeTransparent(img.GetPixel(2, 2))
    Me.TransparencyKey = img.GetPixel(2, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the code below to get the exact thing you are looking for.

If anything extra is needed please ad a comment and I will update the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use TransparencyKey for transparent form.

eg.

```
TransparencyKey = Color.Red
Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Now run the form you will find that the button1 has a hole in it.

So using this method you can create a mask image in paint for which part has to be transparent and apply that image to form and voila the form is now transparent.

Edit:
Sorry for late reply.

**Following is your code modified to suit your requirement**

```
Public Sub New()

    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim img As Bitmap = CType(Me.BackgroundImage, Bitmap)

    'img.MakeTransparent(img.GetPixel(2, 2))
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.TransparencyKey = img.GetPixel(2, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: While this maybe an old post, top google result.. A shorten example that may work for some people is simply this `TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor`.. But make sure your forms backcolor is not in the image your using or any other controls on the form.. Still set your form backcolor to have a unqiue color

Answer (score 2):

Set Form's TransparencyKey color property same as form's Background color property

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods you could use.

- Use the forms TransparencyKey
- Override OnPaintBackground (WM_ERASEBKGND)
- Override WndProc and handle the paint messages (WM_NCPAINT, WM_PAINT, etc)

I recommend overriding the window procedure to get optimal results.

Answer (score -2):

```
Me.Opacity = 0
```

Be warned that:

1. This is for the entire form, rather than just the background.  There are work-arounds to make certain parts more opague.
2. It's only psuedo-transparency where it takes a snapshot of what's behind it.  It's smart enough to know when you move the form, but not when you move other transparent objects on top of the form.

Comment: This will also hide all control elements on the form.