# WinForms draw a non transparent string into a transparent form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building an app in which I have to show a semitransparent form. I need to draw some text on that form too, to let the user know some info.
However, the strings I draw are also semitransparent and are difficult to read. I was wondering if there is a way to draw a non transparent string into a semitransparent form.
I'm using .NET 4.0, C# and WinForms technology.
For the moment I use the DrawString method on the Graphics form, but using a Label had no effect at all tho.
Browsing StackOverflow I found this [How do I make my form transparent, but what I draw on it not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541837/how-do-i-make-my-form-transparent-but-what-i-draw-on-it-not) but it refers to WPF, and I'm using plain old WinForms.

Cheers.

Comment: In VB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518020/how-can-i-set-a-form-to-have-a-transparent-background

Comment: You can have a partially opaque window, makes the text opaque too as you found out, or a fully transparent window with non-opaque text using the TransparencyKey property.  If you want both then you need a sandwich of both.  Two windows on top of each other.  Display the 2nd window with the Show(owner) overload.

Comment: Can you paste the code you use to make the form semi-transparent?

Comment: To make the form semi transparent I just set the opacity property to 10%

Comment: May be this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/textonglass.aspx?msg=1686684) will be helpfull?

Comment: I've opted for Hans Passant solution. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but does putting the labels in a panel that has a background work?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you - it will give you a fully transparent form with non-transparent text:

in InitializeComponent:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
TransparencyKey = BackColor;
ShowInTaskbar = false;
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

in OnPaint override:

```
g.DrawString(...) // Use some SolidBrush.
```

However, if you don't want fully transparent form (this won't sound nice but should work), then you can use **TWO** forms: One with semi transparent background, no text. Other one (on top of the previous one) with fully transparent background and non-transparent text. You can bind location, size and visibility of one form to another to keep them in synch.

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I took as someone commented on the original post. Thanks mate.