# Custom Background with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net

So I have this desktop app that I want to look like a credit card terminal. I have the image already, I just need the windows form background to be the image. The image is not square, there are irregular curved lines. I set the background image to display it but the BackColor is Active Border. I'd like it to be so it is transparent along the edges, not the ugly default grey color. I currently don't have anything happening on the form load except centering:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CenterToScreen()
End Sub
```

What can I do so my app only shows the graphics of my background image and not the rest of the square shape of the form?

Comment: Have you looked into the form's `TransparencyKey` and `Opacity` properties?? Could that get you there?? - Basically, you could color the whole outside of your image some irregular color using a graphic program (even paintbrush could do this) and then set the `TransparencyKey` to match that color....

Answer (score 0):

You could the background to transparent 1st:

Link > [How can I set a form to have a transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518020/how-can-i-set-a-form-to-have-a-transparent-background)

Then set the image to your background and bring to front infront of the transparent image if necessary.